# Getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'float' with a print statement

Tags: python

I am getting a `TypeError` for the following code:

```
print ("Intercept = %f") % (intercept)
print ("Slope = %f") % (gradient)
```

The error message is

> unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'float'.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You used the Python 2 syntax of `print` in Python 3. In effect, you’re applying the `%` operator to the *result* of `print(...)` instead of its argument.

Use this instead:

```
print(("Intercept = %f") % (intercept))
print(("Slope = %f") % (gradient))
```